# Iterate over IP addresses

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have two IP addresses (in .NET, the `System.Net.IPAddress` class). How can I iterate over all the IP addresses between two given addresses?

For example, let one address be 192.168.1.1 and the other 192.168.2.3. I want to somehow iterate over all the addresses in between and print them to the console.

Thank you.

Comment: You need the subnet to know what is a valid address between the two IPs

Comment: I can't think of very many "good" reasons to scan a network for valid IP addresses, but I can think of quite a few nefarious ones.

Comment: @Randolpho - the example specifies internal network addresses, so there might well be a "good" reason.

Comment: @Randolpho I'm building an app to give remote commands to multiple computers using WMI. I need a domain admin account name and password to do anything to the computers.
When did IP (and even port) scanning become such a crime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I ended up using the approach provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172699/80003).

It's a little more complicated but it works well without using deprecated properties. It converts IP addresses to `uint`s, increments them, then converts them back.

Answer (score -3):

IPv4 addresses are basically `Int64`'s with a different notation. So you can do the following:

```
for (var i = fromAddress.Address; i <= toAddress.Address; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(new IPAddress(i));
}
```

The Address property is deprecated but that may not be a concern to you.

Comment: This does not work. Let's say I want to increment from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.3. `fromAddress.Address` is 16885952 and `toAddress.Address` is 50440384. If I run the for loop, it outputs 192.168.1.1; 193.168.1.1; 194.168.1.1... and it keeps going on and on.

Comment: This just caused an infinite loop, bringing the system to a halt.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work because Windows is little endian and network addresses are big endian.