# Generate IP range from Start of IP address and count of IP Addresses

Tags: c#, networking

So I have seen plenty of examples out on the web that shows how to get the full range of IP's if you know the start IP and the End IP but what I need is is something telling me the full IP range after providing the code with the Start IP and the Number of IP addresses needed.

So for example if I provide the IP address of 192.168.0.1 as the starting IP and the number of IP's needed of 60 IP's, the results should come back with a result of

```
StartIP = 192.168.0.1
EndIP = 192.168.0.61
IPCount = 60
```

I have seen the IPNetwork library but that requires the use of CIDR which we are not using.

EDIT:

What I have tried is the following.

I have tried IPNetwork which when using that it is requiring CIDR as stated above we are not using CIDR so that is of no good to me.

I thought of the very basics of just take the last octet and add to that number, so if the last octet is 2 and the number of IP's are 60 than the new last octet is 62. Pretty simple for that but when the last octet is something like 200 and the number of IP's that are needed is 70 than we can't just add to that last octet because that would end you up with 270 for a last octet and since you cannot go over 255 there is an issue. 
Now how to calculate what that IP should actually be is another issue. I as far as what code have I tried, nothing that is of much use on here because it has showed to be completely the wrong direction to go since I have discovered the problems that I noted above. 
I'm not looking for someone to straight up write the code for me I can write my own code but what I am hoping for is for someone to get me on the right track to move forward with this. Unfortunately I have never been one for IP addresses. I spent a very short time in School to learn how to calculate IP addresses. That was 14 years ago and only for a small part of a semester.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: You can't do that without also supplying a range, otherwise the code can generate addresses outside the desired subnet. Just generate an entire block (see duplicate) using `new IPRange("192.168.1.0/24").GetAllIP().Skip(1).Take(60)`, or you could generate a string for `new IPRange("192.168.0.1-61").GetAllIP()`. If your question is how to actually do the latter, please show your current code.

Comment: Where is it that there is a duplicate?

Comment: Apparently @Guffa reopened the question. The duplicate I linked was [C#: Enumerate IP addresses in a range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172677/c-enumerate-ip-addresses-in-a-range).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse the IP address to a 32 bit value (as that's what it really represents), then you can easily loop through a range and create IP addresses for them.

Conversion:

```
public static uint ParseIP(string ip) {
  byte[] b = ip.Split('.').Select(s => Byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(b);
  return BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, 0);
}

public static string FormatIP(uint ip) {
  byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(ip);
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(b);
  return String.Join(".", b.Select(n => n.ToString()));
}
```

Creating a range:

```
string StartIP = "192.168.0.1";
int IPCount = 61;

uint n = ParseIP("192.168.0.1");
string[] range = new string[IPCount];
for (uint i = 0; i < IPCount; i++) {
  range[i] = FormatIP(n + i);
}
```

Comment: Guffa this is a lot more than I was asking for and I appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't recognize subnets, generating the ip `192.168.1.0` (the broadcast address for the "next" subnet `192.168.1.0/24`) when more than 5 addresses are requested from starting address `192.168.0.250`. The user must input in which subnet(s) they want the adresses to be, otherwise generating addresses is of little use. This is why I linked to that duplicate, where you can parse one or more blocks in CIDR notation (`192.168.0.0/24`) and take as many addresses as you need. And no, [you can't simply skip `.0` and `.255`](http://serverfault.com/questions/10985/is-x-y-z-0-a-valid-ip-address).

Comment: So maybe  this is a bit out of the scope here but like an test I just ran with this code. Start IP 192.168.0.250  and IP count of 20 my end IP ends up being 192.168.1.13 
Does that actually fall in line with proper IP addressing, <-- Probably did not ask that to clearly

Comment: @CodeCaster: If you read the edit in the question, you see that the op specifically asks for a solution that can wrap from one C-net to the next.

Comment: @Guffa and if you read my comment, you'll see that you generate `192.168.1.0`, which may or may not be a valid assignable IP address depending on the subnet. Your code does assumptions that may be invalid.

Comment: @scripter78: Yes, that is what you get if you want to have addresses that wrap from one subnet to the next. Naturally that is not how addresses are allocated in the real word, that follows other, sometimes completely arbitrary, rules. The first and/or last address of a C-net is normally reserved for a router or similar.

Comment: @CodeCaster: No, those assumptions are made specifically in the question.

Comment: Please point out where OP said _"the IPs can span multiple subnets and must include subnet and broadcast addresses"_. Until that has been made sure, this most likely is not what OP needs.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Please read te question instead of inventing things that should be in it.

Comment: In all fairness the question was a bit open ended, that being said Guffa and CodeCaster both make very excellent points. This post actually cleared a lot of my own concerns up. With this information everyone has provided I was able to go back to the department at my work that is requesting this project and get clearer expectations of what they were wanting. Given the I'm not happy with the request that they are asking for but at least it is clearer now. Basically they will never start an IP address off at a high ending octet they would start off at all times with a 5 or something really low.

Comment: in addition t o that they would never provide more than 60 ip addresses. So that all being said the looping to new subnet would not be an issue. I wish they were more clear about their request the first 5 times I asked

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I didn't think that it was you who downvoted, as that happened two days later. Strange behaviour.